Length of a regular arc
I have to prove that if two arc are (positive) equivalent, they have the same length.
Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta:[c,d]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ two differentiable arcs and let $h:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ a diffeomorfism (at least differentiable one time) such that $\alpha(t)=\beta(h(t))$ $\forall t\in [a,b]$ with $h'(t)>0$ $\forall t\in [a,b]$. Let $L(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta)$ the lengths of the two arcs.
$$L(\alpha) = \int_a^b \|\alpha'(t)\|\, dt 
= \int_a^b \|\beta'(h(t))\| \cdot h'(t) \, dt 
= \int_{h(a)}^{h(b)} \|\beta'(s)\| \, ds 
= L(\beta)
$$
Why in the last step I can conclude that I have the entire length of $\beta$?

$h(a) = c$ and $h(b) = d$ since $h$ is strictly increasing and bijective

thank you very much!

Notation: Use \| x \| for norm bars with better spacing: $| x |$.

@julio_es_sui_glace Make your comment into an answer so that the question can be marked as Answered.

As requested by @SammyBlack , here is the reason why everything goes out as desired.
$\forall x \in [a,b], h'(x)>0$ so $h$ is increasing. Furthermore, $h$ is surjective since it is a diffeomorphism. Now for these reasons, we have
$$h(a) = h(\min [a,b]) = \min h([a,b]) = \min [c,d] = c$$
and
$$h(b) = h(\max [a,b]) =\max h([a,b]) = \max [c,d] = d$$
thus
$$\int_{h(a)}^{h(b)} \|\beta'(s)\| \, ds =\int_{c}^{d} \|\beta'(s)\| \, ds 
= L(\beta)$$
